# How to remove this "0": {from an array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

```
$test = array('hola'=>'mundo','salami'=>'frito');
$data = array(
    'gift_promoted' => '',
    'questions' => array(
        0 => array(
            'extra' => array()
        )
    ),
    'quiz' => array(
        'extra' => array(),
        $test
    )
);

print json_encode($data);
```

Actual result:

```
{"gift_promoted":"","questions":[{"extra":[]}],"quiz":{"extra":[],"0":{"hola":"mundo","salami":"frito"}}}
```

[annotated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGnF3.png)

I need this is:

```
{"gift_promoted":"","questions":[{"extra":[]}],"quiz":{"extra":[],"hola":"mundo","salami":"frito"}}
```

Comment: You can use `unset`.

Comment: The duplicate is wrong. This question is about changing [0=>$v] to $v, which is not exactly deleting an element.

Comment: Exactly the issue is not duplicated

Comment: You probably want array_merge after creating the `$data` array.

Comment: `'quiz' => array('extra' => array()) + $test` is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a little dirty:

```
$test = array('hola'=>'mundo','salami'=>'frito'); $data = array(
     'gift_promoted' => '',
     'questions' => array(
         0 => array(
             'extra' => array()
         )
     ),
     'quiz' => array(
         'extra' => array(),
         //$test --> remove this.
     ) );

 foreach($test as $key => $value) {     $data['quiz'][$key]=$value; }

 print json_encode($data);
```